How do I write a PowerShell script to recursively bulk-rename files and folders, to remove hidden characters?
I've got close to a million files and folders on a Windows server with file names that are polluted with Apple MacOS special characters in random places. Some of these characters create robocopy errors when archiving.
The offending special characters are:

Zero Width Space (0x200b)
U+F028 Unicode character

I can find these files in Windows File Explorer by using these commands in the Search tool.

name:~"​"
name:~""

I wish to rename them, deleting the special character.
I have Googled at length and PowerShell seems to be the way forward.
I've devised a script that I could run from the root path of the drive, but I am not sure if this script is optimised (or a wise choice).
#Set location to run from
set-location -Path "P:\"

#Rename folders containing Zero Width Spaces
$folders = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Directory | Sort-Object
$folders | ForEach-Object {
    set-location $_.Parent.FullName
    Rename-Item $_.Name ($_.Name -replace("​", ""))
}

#Rename folders containing U+F028
$folders = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Directory | Sort-Object
$folders | ForEach-Object {
    set-location $_.Parent.FullName
    Rename-Item $_.Name ($_.Name -replace("", ""))
}

#Rename files containing Zero Width Spaces
$files = Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse
$files | ForEach-Object {
 Rename-Item -Path $_.PSPath -NewName $_.Name.replace("​","")
}

#Rename files containing U+F028
$files = Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse
$files | ForEach-Object {
 Rename-Item -Path $_.PSPath -NewName $_.Name.replace("","")
}

I believe the logic is correct, but my artificial test scenario (some demo files and folders on a local HDD) works, but fails on an external USB drive scenario with a bigger file set.
I am worried about performance and lack of logging.

I won't tell you whether to pull the trigger on this or not, and I'd be very careful to act on advice you get here, if I were you. However, how about first running a script that only lists what renaming it would do, instead of hoping for the best and just running the real thing?

I'll note that one potential issue is that removing a character can cause duplicate file names. For example, what if I have ab.txt and a.txt in the same location and I rename all files to remove any occurrence of the letter b? Another more general issue is that files you rename may be referred to from other files or parts of the system, and you'd likely be breaking those links - but that's an issue regardless of whether your script does what the tin says. It's one more reason to list before you execute, so you can check for such issues.

Just so you know, if you have a working script, and you just want to make sure that you're following best practices and are seeking general feedback, the [codereview.se] Stack Exchange site might be a more suitable place to post your question. Before you post there, please make sure your question is on-topic and that you read the guide on how to ask a good question.

A pure PowerShell solution based on cmdlets will be slow, and Grismar makes  good points about potential name collisions and broken symlinks. Leaving that aside, you can try something like the following. Note that -WhatIf previews the naming operations: Get-ChildItem -Force -Recurse -Name | Where-Object { [System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($_) -match '[\uF028\u200b]' } |  Sort-Object -Descending { ($_ -replace '[^\\]').Length } |  Rename-Item -LiteralPath { $_ } -NewName { [System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($_ -replace '[\uF028\u200b]') } -WhatIf

Wow. Thank you all! These comments have all been super constructive and helpful.
Hoppeduppeanut my script was not, in fact, working when I tried it on an external USB drive. But did work on a local folder.
@mklement0 your insights and example script were particularly fabulous and I very much appreciate the time you've taken. -WhatIf is a massive help and helps to address the concerns from others about running a script more or less blind. I found an instance where the filename was just one character... and it was one of these special characters!
Logging to TXT would be good too...

Glad to hear it was helpful, @mrEdge; my pleasure. As for logging to a text file: Unfortunately, as of PowerShell 7.4.x, you can not capture output produced by -WhatIf. See GitHub issue #9870 for a proposal to change that in the future.

It works for me on a fat32 formatted usb drive with the file created in cmd.  You don't need the parentheses with -replace, but it happens to work anyway.

As usual the script has to be encoded utf8 WITH BOM.
